# Make color of icon in navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation

I'm trying to learn Android, and I'm attempting to make a navigation drawer.

My goal is to achieve something like this:

[image: Goal]

But my result looks like this:

[image: Result]

This is my style.xml:

```
    </style>

    <style name="Base.AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/md_deep_purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/md_deep_purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/md_white_1000_50</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NavigationViewTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="textAppearanceListItem">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2</item>
        <item name="android:icon">@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

This is my navigation_drawer_header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        >
</FrameLayout>
```

Can anyone suggest to me how these should be corrected?

Comment: I think two images are same

Comment: @ted Yow want the clicked row image and text to change its color?

Comment: my icon in navigation drawer have  change color to gray. I just want it to have their default color

Comment: That is because of applied style navigationViewTheme.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the NavigationView add tint to the icons.
To avoid this you can add

```
navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

You can add color state list. Get a look into [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's really a great help to me